# Yarn container out of memory when using large memory mapped file

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, memory-mapped-files

I am using hadoop 2.4. The reducer use several large memory mapped files (about 8G total). The reducer itself uses very little memory. To my knowledge, the memeory mapped file (`FileChannel.map(readonly)`) also uses little memory (managed by OS instead of JVM).

I got this error:

```
Container [pid=26783,containerID=container_1389136889967_0009_01_000002] 
is running beyond physical memory limits. 
Current usage: 4.2 GB of 4 GB physical memory used;
5.2 GB of 8.4 GB virtual memory used. Killing container
```

Here was my settings:

```
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx2048m

mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=4096
```

So I adjust the parameter to this and works:

```
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx10240m

mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=12288
```

I further adjust the parameters and get it work like this:

```
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx2048m

mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=10240
```

**My question is:** why I need the yarn container to have about 8G more memory than the JVM size? The culprit seems to be the large Java memory mapped files I used (each about 1.5G, sum up to about 8G). Isn't the memory mapped files managed by the OS and they supposed to be sharable by multiple processes (e.g. reducers)?

I use AWS m2.4xlarge instance (67G memory) and it has about 8G  unused and the OS should have sufficient memory. In current settings, there are only about 5 reducers available for each instance, and each reducer has extra 8G memory. This just looks very stupid.

Comment: Perhaps reducer copies the input data into memory while processing it, and these data either don't get discarded before job stops, or GC is not very quick at cleaning up?

Comment: I use the java Runtime class to print out maxMemory, totalMemory and freeMemory. The max is less than 2G, the free is about 1.2G. The actually memory used by the reducer is only about 512M. So I think it is not about garbage collection.

Comment: the java memory mapped is managed by OS. It should be reused by multiple processes (reducers?) I just wonder how to yarn node manager interact with these memory mapped files?

Comment: here is what I read more about java memory mapped file: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/683614/Things-to-Know-about-Memory-Mapped-File-in-Java

Answer (score 2):

From the logs, it seems that you have enabled `yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled` and `yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled` properties in `yarn-site.xml`. If these checks are enabled, then `NodeManger` may kill container(s), if it detects that the container(s) exceeded the resource limits. In your case, physical memory exceeded the configured value (=4G) so `NodeManager` killed the task (running within the container).

In normal cases, heap memory (defined using `-Xmx` property in `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` and `mapreduce.map.java.opts` configurations) is defined 75-80% of the total memory (defined using `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` configurations). However, in your case due to Java Memory Mapped Files implementation, non-heap memory requirements are higher than heap memory, and thats why you had to keep quite large gap between total and heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link, there may be a need to tune the property  mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent

[Out of memory error in Mapreduce shuffle phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298357/out-of-memory-error-in-mapreduce-shuffle-phase)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.   
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.